# React Native onLayout with React Hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I want to measure the size of a **[React Native View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/view#docsNav)** every time it renders, and save it to state. If element layout didn't change the effect should not run.

It's easy to do with a class based component, where [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout) can be used. But what do I do in a functional component where I use React Hooks?

I've read about [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect). If that's the way to go, do you have an example of how to use it?

I made this custom hook called useDimensions. This is how far I've got:

```js
const useDimensions = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({});
  useLayoutEffect(
    () => {
      setDimensions(/* Get size of element here? How? */);
    },
    [ref.current],
  );
  return [ref, dimensions];
};
```

And I use the hook and add the ref to the view that I want to measure the dimensions of.

```js
const [ref, dimensions] = useDimensions();

return (
  <View ref={ref}>
    ...
  </View>
);
```

I've tried to debug `ref.current` but didn't find anything useful there. I've also tried [measure()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/direct-manipulation#measurecallback) inside the effect hook:

```js
ref.current.measure((size) => {
  setDimensions(size); // size is always 0
});
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you could like a more self-contained version of this here is a custom hook version for React Native:

```js
const useComponentSize = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState(null);

  const onLayout = useCallback(event => {
    const { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    setSize({ width, height });
  }, []);

  return [size, onLayout];
};

const Component = () => {
  const [size, onLayout] = useComponentSize();
  return <View onLayout={onLayout} />;
};
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I like self-contained custom hooks that allow me to do as little as possible in the components using them.

Comment: This is a great hook.  Is there anyway to get the x and y position as well?

Comment: My answer below has an example for getting the position as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859317/1547857

Comment: Great answer.   Solved an issue I was having.

Comment: For typescript you had to change something to avoid type errors: 

`const useComponentSize = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState<null | { width: number; height: number }>(
    null
  );

  const onLayout = useCallback((event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
    const { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    setSize({ width, height });
  }, []);

  return { size, onLayout };
};
`

Answer (score 6):

You had the right idea, it just needed a couple of tweaks... mainly, handing in the element ref and using elementRef (not `elementRef.current`) in the `useEffect` dependency array.

(Regarding `useEffect` vs `useLayoutEffect`, as you're only measuring rather than mutating the DOM then I believe `useEffect` [is the way to go](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect), but you can swap it out like-for-like if you need to)

```
const useDimensions = elementRef => {
   const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
   useEffect(() => {
      const el = elementRef.current;
      setDimensions({ width: el.clientWidth, height: el.clientHeight });
    }, [elementRef]);
    return [dimensions];
};
```

Use it like this:

```
function App() {
  const divRef = useRef(null);
  const [dimensions] = useDimensions(divRef);
  return (
    <div ref={divRef} className="App">
      <div>
        width: {dimensions.width}, height: {dimensions.height}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-driscoll-73i4q)

**Edited to Add React Native version:**

For React Native you can use `useState` with `onLayout` like this:

```
const App=()=>{
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({width:0, height:0})
    return (
      <View onLayout={(event) => {
                const {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                setDimensions({width:width, height:height});
        }}>
        <Text}>
          height: {dimensions.height} width: {dimensions.width}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I do it in **react native**?

Answer (score 6):

As a refinement to
[matto1990's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57792001/1547857), and to answer Kerkness's question - here's an example custom hook that supplies the x, y position as well as the layout size:

```
const useComponentLayout = () => {
  const [layout, setLayout] = React.useState(null);

  const onLayout = React.useCallback(event => {
    const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    setLayout(layout);
  }, [])

  return [layout, onLayout]
}

const Component = () => {
  const [{ height, width, x, y }, onLayout] = useComponentLayout();
  return <View onLayout={onLayout} />;
};
```

Comment: note: the x and y here are relative to the parent component right?