# React Native - use useDimensions hook in stylesheet

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

How do you use dimensions returned from a hook in RN in the Stylesheet?

for example

```
import { useDimensions } from '@react-native-community/hooks';

const ProfileEditScreen = () => {
  const { width, height } = useDimensions().window;
  ...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profileEditContainer__form: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    height: 40,
    width: width - width / 4,
    borderColor: Colors.defaultColor,
    borderWidth: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  ...
```

In the example above, `width` is `not defined`.

In the past (class components), I used to have a top-level

```
const { width: WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Can't really do that anymore with functional components.. any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744045/13107433) could help.

Comment: hooks by definition can only be used in functional components. Here the stylesheet is not part of the functional component. If you want to use it in stylesheet, `Dimensions.get('window')` is the only way

Answer (score 1):

1. You only can use hooks in functional components.
2. For your example I would still suggest to use `Dimensions.get('window')`.