# Draw bounding box after image has been resized react native

Tags: react-native, image

I am trying to draw a bounding box around the monkey's face in this [image](https://discovery.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/discovery/fullset/2021/4/30/GettyImages-1189192456.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.406.406.suffix/1619849704543.jpeg). The coordinates I want to use are the following:

```
64,111
347,111, 
64,304, 
347,304
```

This is the desired look:

[image]

I am displaying the image with `resizeMode` = `contain` which results in the bounding box being misplaced and the wrong size.

I think the top-left of the rectangle should be at 64,111 using position absolute and the width and height should just be the difference between the points (width = 283 and height = 193). I know that since the image is not being displayed at its full height and width I need to scale down the bounding box accordingly. However, I can't figure out what the image's final size is after it has been resized. How can I figure this out in order to display my bounding box correctly? When I use onLayout like so:

```
onLayout={(event) => {
const {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
}}
```

the height is always incorrect as it includes the total height of its image and background (when I all I need is the height of the image itself)

Here is my code so far: https://snack.expo.dev/@melampus123/forlorn-raisins

Comment: onLayout will give you height,width, x and y, although it only happens after the image is rendered

Comment: onLayout gives the entire view of the image's height (the width is right but the hight includes the much taller orange background)

Comment: Have you tried using the width and height from [onLoad](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onload)

Comment: Here's where im currently at https://snack.expo.dev/jXHQgI5WJ

Comment: I think the dimensions provided from the onLoad function is the original size of the image. If you toggle resizeMode between contain and cover you will still get the same width and height. https://snack.expo.dev/3r39b2PK3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was harder than expected, because as you said, `onLayout` doesnt include the size the image was scaled down. I thought onLoad would scale the image down as well, but that was a no go. So I guess the only way to know the downscale size is to just recalculate it yourself. You can do this if you know the original image size, and the size of the view  it will be contained to.

useImageSize hook:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
export default function useImageSize(imgUri) {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    Image.getSize(
      imgUri,
      (width, height) => setSize({ width, height }),
      setError
    );
  }, []);
  return [size, error];
}
```

view size hook (I actually use the hook alot so its in typescript)

```js
/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738500/react-native-onlayout-with-react-hooks*/
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { LayoutChangeEvent, LayoutRectangle } from 'react-native';

const defaultInitVal = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
};

export default function useLayout(
  initialVal?: Partial<LayoutRectangle>
): [LayoutRectangle, (l: LayoutChangeEvent) => void] {
  initialVal = initialVal || {};
  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    ...defaultInitVal,
    ...initialVal,
  } as LayoutRectangle);

  const onLayout = useCallback((e: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
    const layout = e.nativeEvent.layout;
    setSize(layout);
  }, []);
  return [size, onLayout];
}
```

Bringing it all together:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import useLayout from './useLayout';
import useImageSize from './useImageSize'

const imgUri =
  'https://discovery.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/discovery/fullset/2021/4/30/GettyImages-1189192456.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.406.406.suffix/1619849704543.jpeg';

export default function App() {
  
  const [imgLayout, onImageLayout] = useLayout();
 
  const [imgDimensions,imgSizeErr] = useImageSize(imgUri) 
  const [boundingBox, setBoundingBox] = React.useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!imgDimensions.width || !imgDimensions.height) {
      console.log('Image dimensions not loaded yet');
    } else {
      const { width: originalWidth, height: originalHeight } = imgDimensions;
      console.log(imgDimensions);
      const { width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight } = imgLayout;
      const imgAspectRatio = originalWidth / originalHeight;
      // find image dimension closest to container dimension
      const widthDiff = Math.abs(originalWidth - containerWidth);
      const heightDiff = Math.abs(originalHeight - containerHeight);
      let imgWidth, imgHeight;
      // if width is closest then  scale imgHeight to containerWidth
      if (widthDiff < heightDiff) {
        imgWidth = containerWidth;
        imgHeight = imgWidth * imgAspectRatio;
      }
      // if height is closest scale imgWidth to containerWidth
      else {
        imgHeight = containerHeight;
        imgWidth = imgHeight * imgAspectRatio;
      }
      setBoundingBox({
        x: imgLayout.left || imgLayout.x,
        y: imgLayout.top || imgLayout.y,
        width: imgWidth,
        height: imgHeight,
      });
    }
  }, [imgDimensions, imgLayout]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('boundingBox:\n' + JSON.stringify(boundingBox, null, 2));
  }, [boundingBox]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('imgLayout:\n' + JSON.stringify(imgLayout, null, 2));
  }, [imgLayout]);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Monkey </Text>
      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
          uri: imgUri,
        }}
        onLayout={onImageLayout}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          borderWidth: 3,
          ...boundingBox,
          // I thought that onLayout would provide
          // values reflecting the movement caused by
          // justifyContent and alignItems but it doesnt
          // so this I'll just calculate the centering
          top: boundingBox.y + (imgLayout.height - boundingBox.height) / 2,
          zIndex: 400,
        }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  image: {
    width: 300,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/MqyclkQjJ)

Comment: will this work in javaScript / expo Snack?

Comment: here is the above code working in java script: https://snack.expo.dev/X3cmdHz_e. It seems that a box is just being drawn around the entire image? The requirement is to draw around a specific part of the image given coordinates based on the original image. I added an image to the question to make this more clear

Comment: I didnt realize that you had a box that fit within the original image, who's position you wanted scaled down to whatever size the image currently is. Its kind of the same process. You'll need to know how much the image has been scaled, then multiply your points by that value

Comment: The width of the box is a little long and the height a little short so I havent edited the answer but this what I have so far https://snack.expo.dev/PD7OHda7i

Comment: turns out the width is okay, I just needed to offset the container's position. But the height still falls short

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/UjTcp3pUer

Comment: Even with the original image dimensions, my bounding box isnt like that in the picture